# Copying columns from one layer to another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, copy, column

In QGIS 3 I couldn't find any suitable answer for my struggle. I have two layers with different objects (buildings from different areas). I want them to have same columns, but creating one by one is very time consuming, so I was wondering if there's easier solution to copy empty columns from one layer to another?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 11):

In the processing toolbox, search for <kbd>Refactor fields</kbd>.

[Here the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) (3.22).

You can select your layer to modify as `Input layer` and load field from another layer (see the combo below under the Fields mapping list)

[image: Refactor Fields]